# how can this inner enum code be improved?

Tags: java, enums

I have this construct:

```
public class Constants {
 enum SystemA implements Marker {
    ConstOne(1), ConstTwo(2), ConstThree(3);
    SystemA(int i)
   {
      number = i;
   }
   int number;
 }

  enum SystemB implements Marker {
    ConstFour(4), ConstFive(5), ConstSix(6);
  SystemB(int i)
   {
      number =i;
   } 
   int number;
 }
}
```

I have `Marker` so I can pass to method like this:
`method(Constants.SystemA)` or `method(Constants.SystemB)`

What is the best way to list all the enum values?  I also want to make sure that it is not duplicating the number in any of the enums.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. People are very willing to help, but help them help you by doing a few simple things (like formatting).

Comment: Why do they need to be two separate classes?

Comment: I think you'll be interested interested in this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). If so show your support and help get it to beta. It's almost there.

Comment: T.J Crowder, thankyou. looks like someone formatted it already.

Comment: Are you talking about SystemA and SystemB ? Values for each of these come from different client options. So in the code I want to see SystemA.ConstOne and SystemB.ConstFour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the contract of the two enums is the same, you can have it into one single enum.
However, in order to distinguish the two systems, you can have a separate "SystemType" enum that will contain A, B, ... and you can assign a SystemType to each constant in your System enum.

Furthermore, your SystemType enum can provide an instance method that will return all the systems for a given type, so that you can iterate through only that subset as needed.

As for the numbering, if the sequence is as simple as in your example, you can make use of the ordinal() method of the enum constants so that you'll simply rely on the constant declaration order (perhaps with some math added). Here's what I mean:

```
public enum SystemType {
    A, B;

    public Set<System> getSystems() {
        Set<System> systems = EnumSet.noneOf(System.class);
        for (System system : System.values()) {
            if (system.getType() == this) {
                systems.add(system);
            }
        }
        // you could also store this result
        // as an instance variable for caching.
        return systems; 
    }
}

public enum System {
    ConstOne(SystemType.A),
    ConstTwo(SystemType.A),
    ConstThree(SystemType.A),
    ConstFour(SystemType.B),
    ConstantFive(SystemType.B);

    private final SystemType systemType;

    private System(final SystemType systemType) {
        this.systemType = systemType;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return ordinal() + 1;
    }

    public SystemType getType() {
        return systemType;
    }

}
```

This is of course useless if you really need to define different contracts for the different system types (methods that only make sense for SystemX or whatever).

P.S.:
Of course, `System` is a really bad name, as it hides the `java.lang.System` class.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are declaring all enums in code, it is your responsibility to provide non-overlapping numbers, if you need this.
The more interesting question is: Why would you need this? It smells like you are using enums for things they weren't designed for.

Comment: I have specified why I need this. I need to be able to have enum constants, but I want them to be divided into categories and accessed as such. I could simply have different enum and be done with it, but I also want to have them all passed to a a method to   do something with them. i can resolve that with a Marker interface.  The question is in what way am I using them in an unintended fashion. please clarify.

Comment: You are imposing a contract (non-overlapping numbers) to several enums, which is not exactly standard use. 
Since Java does not support inheriting enums, it just might be the wrong feature to use and you might be better off with a standard abstract base class and various subclasses.

To answer the enumeration question: Since you already have a common interface, just stick them in a Set<Marker> or a Map<Marker>

Answer (score 0):

I would rely on one class - a *factory* class - to create and control the instances of your System classes.

Comment: what do you mean factory class ? They are enums. I have stuck them in a class because I want all these enums to be in one place